# Eclipse server location - workspace metadata vs installation folder

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, deployment, jrebel

When I go to server configuration in Eclipse, it let me choose three different configurations for server location

- Workspace metadata
- Installation folder
- Custom location

How does the workspace metadata option actually work? Does it create a copy of server runtime from installation path to workspace metadata, deploy there and run that instance? Does this provide any other benefit besides not messing the actual CATALINA_HOME?

In short, what is exactly `org.eclipse.wst.server.core` under .metadata/.plugins and what's it relation to CATALINA_HOME given as Tomcat installation folder?

When I'm running and deploying Tomcat from Eclipse using installation folder as server location, I couldn't get JRebel to reload the changes, even if log shows the class is being monitored, instrumented etc. When I switched to user workspace metadata as server location, JRebel started working.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer for sure what's the difference, but to best of my knowledge, it simply changes where the Tomcat picks up apps it's supposed to deploy.

Why does JRebel work with workspace metadata selection and not installation setting? Chance is that you haven't got JRebel configured correctly, namely you're missing a `rebel.xml` (*you said classes were instrumented, but from what directory? Project build or workspace metadata?*). How it could work for you with workspace selection is that perhaps you have automatic publishing enabled on server, this also updates class files in the metadata deployment directory whenever the incremental compilation occurs (*it's probably using exploded deployment there*). If JRebel cannot find `rebel.xml`, it picks up the classes from their original location and as those classes are updated, JRebel also reloads them.